# Foreach in a graph : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: php, graph, foreach

I have a graph which works fine manually (data I put by myself).

```
$(function () {
// Use Morris.Area instead of Morris.Line
    Morris.Area({
        element: 'graph-area',
        padding: 10,
        behaveLikeLine: true,
        gridEnabled: false,
        gridLineColor: '#dddddd',
        axes: true,
        fillOpacity:.7,
        data: [      
            {period: '1', Visites: 10},
            {period: '2', Visites: 78},
            {period: '3', Visites: 97},
            {period: '4', Visites: 45},
        ],
        lineColors:['#E67A77'],
        xkey: 'period',
        ykeys: ['Visites'],
        labels: ['Visites'],
        pointSize: 0,
        lineWidth: 0,
        hideHover: 'auto'

    });
});
```

But then I want to display the data dynamically with a foreach.
I can't get this to work :

```
$(function () {
// Use Morris.Area instead of Morris.Line
    Morris.Area({
        element: 'graph-area',
        padding: 10,
        behaveLikeLine: true,
        gridEnabled: false,
        gridLineColor: '#dddddd',
        axes: true,
        fillOpacity:.7,
        data: [<?php

foreach($ga->getResults() as $result)
{
  echo "{period: '".$result."',";
  echo " Visites: ".$result->getVisitors()."},</br>";
}

?>],
        lineColors:['#E67A77','#79D1CF','#79D1CF'],
        xkey: 'period',
        ykeys: ['Visites'],
        labels: ['Visites'],
        pointSize: 0,
        lineWidth: 0,
        hideHover: 'auto'

    });
});
```

I have this in console error :
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ­<

When I echo my foreach, I get the the following thing with the same symthax. It should work but it's not.

```
{period: '01', Visites: 1},
{period: '02', Visites: 1},
{period: '03', Visites: 3},
{period: '04', Visites: 4},
{period: '05', Visites: 1},
{period: '06', Visites: 5},
{period: '07', Visites: 4},
{period: '08', Visites: 2},
{period: '09', Visites: 6},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're outputting html in your javascript. If you want to echo a newline use `\n`.

```
foreach($ga->getResults() as $result)
{
  echo "{period: '".$result."',";
  echo " Visites: ".$result->getVisitors()."},\n";
}
```